# (PostgreSQL) "Advanced" Check Constraint Question

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints, database-schema

I use PostgreSQL but am looking for SQL answer as standard as possible.

I have the following table "docs" --

```
    Column  |          Type          | Modifiers              
------------+------------------------+--------------------
 id         | character varying(32)  | not null
 version    | integer                | not null default 1
 link_id    | character varying(32)  | 
 content    | character varying(128) | 
Indexes:
    "docs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, version)
```

id and link_id are for documents that have linkage relationship between each other, so link_id self references id.

The problem comes with version. Now id is no longer the primary key (won't be unique either) and can't be referenced by by link_id as foreign key --

```
my_db=# ALTER TABLE docs ADD FOREIGN KEY(link_id) REFERENCES docs (id) ; 
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "docs"
```

I tried to search for check constraint on something like "if exists" but didn't find anything.

Any tip will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do like this:

```
table document (id, common, columns, current_revision)
table revision (id, doc_id, content, version)
```

which means that document has a one-to-many relation with it's revisions, AND a one-to-one to the current revision.

That way, you can always select a complete document for the current revision with a simple join, and you will only have one unique row in your documents table which you can link parent/child relations in, but still have versioning.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking as close to your model as possible, you can split your table into two, one which has 1 row per 'doc' and one with 1 row per 'version':

You have the following table "versions" --

```
    Column  |          Type          | Modifiers              
------------+------------------------+--------------------
 id         | character varying(32)  | not null
 version    | integer                | not null default 1
 content    | character varying(128) | 
Indexes:
    "versions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, version)
```

And the following table "docs" --

```
    Column  |          Type          | Modifiers              
------------+------------------------+--------------------
 id         | character varying(32)  | not null
 link_id    | character varying(32)  | 
Indexes:
    "docs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

now

```
my_db=# ALTER TABLE docs ADD FOREIGN KEY(link_id) REFERENCES docs (id) ;
```

is allowed, and you also want:

```
my_db=# ALTER TABLE versions ADD FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES docs;
```

of course there is nothing stoping you getting a 'combined' view similar to your original table:

```
CREATE VIEW v_docs AS
SELECT id, version, link_id, content from docs join versions using(id);
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to accept your answer only to find that SO has the restriction of only one accepted answer per question. Since I'm more inclined to jishi's answer (simply because it maps closer to my application design), all I can off is an up vote. Sorry for that.

Comment: @jishi's answer is good - I'm happy you you've accepted it. You may need to know about [deferrable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createtable.html#AEN58820) constraints to implement it the way he suggests

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if it's what you want, you can simply create a FOREIGN KEY that includes the version field. That's the only way to point to a unique row...

If that doesn't work, you can write a TRIGGER (for all UPDATEs and INSERTs on the table) that makes the check. Note that you will also need a trigger on the docs table, that restricts modifications on that table that would break the key (such as a DELETE or UPDATE on the key value itself).

You cannot do this with a CHECK constraint, because a CHECK constraint cannot access data in another table.